# Evenly space children but right-align parent with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have the following code to setup a menu. The idea is to have the menu items evenly spaced horizontally, but not have them spaced too far apart when there is extra space. If there is extra space, right now the menu aligns to the left (the green is towards the left side of the yellow).

The aim is to have the menu align to the right side. How can this be achieved?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 5em;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.middle {
  flex: 4;
  background: #ffc;
  display: flex!important; /* this comes from the library i'm using */
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  background: #cfc;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="tagline">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <ul>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *align* the menu items to the right, we can have `margin-left: auto` on the `ul`. And maybe you want to set the *default* `padding` of `ul` to zero too.

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 5em;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.middle {
  flex: 4;
  background: #ffc;
  display: flex!important; /* this comes from the library i'm using */
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto; /* ADDED */
  padding: 0; /* ADDED */
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  background: #cfc;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="tagline">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <ul>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this how you want?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 5em;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.middle {
  flex: 4;
  background: #ffc;
  display: flex!important; /* this comes from the library i'm using */
}
ul {
     display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  background: #cfc;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="tagline">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <ul>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not quite, I want to get the green menu items to align along the right side of the yellow container.

Comment: Now it stretches the menu items across the full width. The aim was to limit the width of the menu items (as I had originally). The goal was to have all the menu items move across to the right side of the yellow box.